# Where can I find review exercises on diffraction and interference?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, resource-recommendations, education, interference, diffraction

I am looking for exercises of the following type to prepare for a final exam.[image]

Comment: Go to your university physics library. Find the section containing textbooks for your type of course. Select a dozen or so and look at the problems in the appropriate chapter. Reviewing the chapter to get a slightly different spin on explaining the physics, while optional, is highly encouraged. Next semester repeat for appropriate course(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first book that comes to mind is **Fundamentals of Physics** by *Resnick, Halliday and Walker*. It contains good amount of exercises on these two chapters.

Another good book is **Concepts of Physics** by *H. C. Verma*. These concepts are covered in Volume 2 of the book. Any chapter in Prof. Verma's book contains a huge number of sophisticated problems, many a times the number ranging to 80 or above.

I would prefer both books equally, but I think (though I cannot guarantee) that Prof. Verma's book has better exercises.