# Struggling with interference

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, resource-recommendations, interference

I was reading the book optics by zajac and hecht. It was a nice one until physics optics, i got that interference becomes when the light is coherent and monochromatic, and it is the superposition of electromagnetic wave, but how i can solve the problems with that? i no understand how to procedure to solve it, is anything that I´m not seeing? there is another soft reference to read about the topic?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21288/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/380518/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score -2):

Struggling with a concept for educational purposes or project? When I think of interference with a visual or optical projection of light, I think of eyesight perception and how that is changed. Maybe with a certain magnification/diffraction lens, with the type of energy collection/reflection in the housing, or both. Then you may want to have a means of contrast to determine the projection and potentially focus. If not viewing data from instruments.